# Comparing unique strings in two columns Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns, string-comparison

I am trying to find a string in Column D and Column H and if they match certain criteria, insert the string "Match" in Column W.

For example, if the string "Auditorium" occurs in Column D and the string "INTERNAL" occurs in Column H on the same row, insert the string "Match" in Column W.

My code below inserts the string "Match" in Column W against all rows that contain the string "INTERNAL" irrespective of the string in Column D!

Any advice would be appreciated!

Row | Column D   | Column H          | Column W

1   | Auditorium | Martin (INTERNAL) | Match

2   | Auditorium | John              |

3   | Theatre    | Edward (INTERNAL) | Match

4   | Theatre    | George            | Match

```
Dim celA
Dim celB
    For Each celA In Range("D1:D50")
        For Each celB In Range("H1:H50")
                If InStr(1, celA.Value, "Auditorium") <> 0 And InStr(1, celB.Value, "INTERNAL") <> 0 Then celB.Offset(0, 10).Value = "Match"
        Next celB
    Next celA
```

Comment: Why use VBA when you can use native Excel to do the same thing?

Comment: What @AJD has said is correct. In cell W1 you could put `=IF(AND(D1="auditorium",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("internal",H1,1))),"Match","")` and copy down as much needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need your inner loop. Once you locate the word *auditorium*, just look across the same row for *internal* and set the value in column W if found.

```
Dim celD
For Each celD In Range("D1:D50")
    If cbool(InStr(1, lcase(celD.Value), "auditorium")) then
        If cbool(InStr(1, lcase(celD.offset(0, 4).Value), "internal")) then
            celD.offset(0, 19) = "Match"
        end if
    end if
Next celD
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, thankyou for your reply. When I run the procedure you provided I receive the message "Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid propert assignement" and the word "LCase" is highlighted on line 3.

Comment: Mea culpa; I put the closing bracket in the wrong place. Fixed above.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, that worked perfectly. Thankyou so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

additional variant to already posted

```
Dim celD As Range, SearchKey$
SearchKey = "*auditorium*internal*"
For Each celD In [D1:D50]
    If LCase(celD.Text & celD.Offset(, 4).Text) Like LCase(SearchKey) Then '.text instead of value|value2 is used to convert #errors into string (e.g. #N/A)
        celD.Offset(, 19) = "Match"
    End If
Next celD
```

Comment: Hi Vasily, your answer also worked perfectly. Thankyou also for your help today.

Answer (score 1):

you can also do that with `AutoFilter()` and thus avoid looping (explanations in comments):

```
With Range("H1", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) 'reference columns "H:D" range from row 1 down to column D last not empty row
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Auditorium" 'filter referenced range on its first column (i.e. column "D") with value "Auditorium
    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*INTERNAL*" 'filter referenced range on its fifth column (i.e. column "H") with value containing "INTERNAL"
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1)) > 1 Then .Resize(, 1).Offset(, 19).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "MATCH" 'if any "data" (i.e. from 2nd row downwards) rows matching criteria then write "MATCH" in corresponding rows of 19th column of referenced range (i.e. column "W")
    If .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Auditorium" And InStr(.Cells(1, 5), "INTERNAL") > 0 Then .Cells(1, 20).Value = "MATCH" 'check first ("Headers") rows too
End With
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filters
```

should your data have a "header" row also, than you could omit the last code line before `End With`